# What does "duplicate class" mean?

Tags: android

I have problem with running my app. All of a sudden, the app began producing this error "duplicate class com.google.android.gms.location.places". 
And I'm not even joking, I've been searching this whole site to fix this error, even deleting all project and creating a new one. But nothing, no. NOTHING solves it!

I believe I've been reading each single thread on this topic. Ofc, there's a solution there! It just happens to not be the correct solution for me...

This is the error line:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1)
```

This is my dependencies and app.gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.qwisenow"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'   // FusedLocationProviderClient
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


        implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:8.7.0'            
        implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.6'  
        implementation 'com.ebanx:swipe-button:0.8.3'               
        implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'         
        implementation 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:3.1.1'      
        implementation 'com.github.aarsy.googlemapsanimations:googlemapsanimations:1.0.5'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28'         
        implementation 'com.vipulasri:ticketview:1.0.7' 
        implementation 'me.philio:pinentryview:1.0.6'   
        implementation 'com.github.ar-android:DrawRouteMaps:1.0.0'  
        implementation 'com.codemybrainsout.onboarding:onboarder:1.0.4'     
        implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'    
    }
```

Can anybody see something looks "duplicate" there? I can't, and I've tried probably 30 solutions on this, but Android Studio keeps give me errors...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gradle, but whatever jar you're using named `classes.jar` has identical `com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza` twice. Is that your own jar or an outside dependency you're using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out! First, I don't find any .jar file in the project actually! Where should it be located?

Comment: Inside your package explorer, there should be a directory that lists all or your .jar dependencies.

Comment: Remove one of these and see what happens: *com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0)* or *(com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1)*

Comment: Hi again, I'm not sure where the package explorer is? And also, I can't find any of those lines you suggest to remove!